# Change background of toolkit:TimePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using `toolkit:TimePicker` in `WPF` as code below

```
<toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="datetimeBeginBackup"
            Format="Custom"
            FormatString="HH:mm:ss"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="#FFFFFF">
    <toolkit:TimePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="toolkit:TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\backup_date_time_picker_bgr.png"/>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\backup_date_time_picker_disable_bgr.png"/>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </toolkit:TimePicker.Style>
</toolkit:TimePicker>
```

When the `datetimeBeginBackup` is disable, the background will be changed with `"backup_date_time_picker_disable_bgr.png"`, it is ok. But the background of `TextBlock Time` is white, this make user hard to see the text. I want to change the background of `TextBlock Time`, but I don't know to do it.

Someone can help me?

Many Thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move *Foreground default value in setter* and on trigger IsEnabled, change Foreground to desired value say Black using Style setter.

```
<toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="datetimeBeginBackup"
            Format="Custom"
            FormatString="HH:mm:ss"
            TextAlignment="Center">
    <toolkit:TimePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="toolkit:TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\backup_date_time_picker_bgr.png"/>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\backup_date_time_picker_disable_bgr.png"/>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </toolkit:TimePicker.Style>
</toolkit:TimePicker>
```